# force install npm package dependencies doesn't work

Tags: javascript, npm

My end goal is to install `grunt-html-validation` and my generic goal is to know how to force npm package dependencies to install.
I started down this path because I get high risk errors when I run `npm audit` which point to qs. When I run `npm install request@latest` and `npm install qs@latest`, I get no errors. After doing so, npm list qs does not reflect the expected results, i.e. for qs to be updated to a recent version as the `npm audit` suggests.

**Command#1:**

```
sudo npm install qs
```

**gets:**

```
npm WARN grunt-html-validation@0.1.18 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
+ qs@6.5.2
added 1 package from 1 contributor, updated 1 package and audited 623 packages in 4.014s
found 19 vulnerabilities (3 low, 10 moderate, 6 high)
```

**Command #2:**

```
sudo npm install request@latest
```

**gets:**

```
+ request@2.88.0
updated 1 package in 2.584s
```

**Command#3:**

```
npm list qs
```

**gets:**

```
grunt-html-validation@0.1.18
|
request@2.34.0
|
qs@0.6.6
```

Observations/questions in my troubleshooting:
- Why won't `gs@0.6.6` update? It is at the end of the dependency chain. I went deleted `@my_project/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs` which didn't help. Then I updated `@my_project/node_modules/request/package.json/dependencies/qs` to `~3.1.0` just to see if it would update results of npm list qs. It did NOT, although `@my_project/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/package.json` reflects version `3.1.0` now. I used npm cache clean several times as well
- Why didn't **Command#1** update `request@2.34.0` in my dependency chain?

I am also getting these warnings on `npm install grunt-html-validation`:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated hoek@0.9.1: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer
npm WARN grunt-html-validation@0.1.18 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: So apparently the problem was that node modules were stored within node modules in my project directory and there were two layers of them like so:
grunt-html-validation => request => qs
and 
request => qs

I had to modify the package.json file for BOTH 'request' folders to a version | do npm cache clean and finally the versions updated.

Comment: You should not be modifying the contents of node_modules, since those changes won't apply to other users downloading your repository

Answer (score 0):

`grunt-html-validation@0.1.18` depends on `request@~2.34.0`, which means that it will install request version 2.34.x regardless of your root package dependencies.

The best solution is for that dependency to update its dependencies, but for a seemingly abandoned package like this one, you can also try using `overrides` in your package.json, e.g.:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-html-validation": "^0.1.18"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "request": "2.88.0"
  }
}
```